# GPIO.add_event_detect callback seems to run but then throws an error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I am new to Python, somewhat new to programming(<3 years with Flutter, C++) So I want to only run my tests when the button is pressed. I wasn't sure if a loop would be a good idea so I went with the event detection. My callback (startProgram) will create and launch a new thread that runs the test I need (I will have multiple different tests eventually). I am running into an issue where startProgram seems to run with a value of true even when the button was not pressed and then it throws the error below.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(start_btn, GPIO.FALLING, callback=startProgram(True), bouncetime=50)
TypeError: Parameter must be callable
```

Here is my code:

```
import iperf3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys

start_btn = 17
stop_btn = 27
start_value = False

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(start_btn, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


ledRed = 13
ledYellow = 6
ledGreen = 5


def toggleGreenLED():
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        turnOffYellowLED()
        GPIO.setup(ledGreen, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(ledGreen, False)
        time.sleep(10)
        GPIO.output(ledGreen, True)
        GPIO.cleanup()
def toggleRedLED():
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        turnOffYellowLED()
        GPIO.setup(ledRed, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(ledRed, False)
        time.sleep(10)
        GPIO.output(ledRed, True)
        GPIO.cleanup()
def turnOnYellowLED():
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(ledYellow, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(ledYellow, False)
def turnOffYellowLED():
        GPIO.output(ledYellow, True)

def runLanTest():
    turnOnYellowLED()
    remote_site = '169.254.66.64'

    #How long to run iperf3 test in seconds
    test_duration = 10

    # Set Iperf Client Options
    # Run 10 parallel streams on port 5201 for duration with reverse
    client = iperf3.Client();
    client.server_hostname = remote_site
    client.zerocopy = True
    client.verbose = False
    client.reverse = True
    client.port = 5201
    client.num_streams = 10
    client.duration = int(test_duration)
    client.bandwidth = 1000000000
    try:
        #run iperf3 test
        result = client.run()
        sent_mbps = int(result.sent_Mbps)
        received_mbps = int(result.received_Mbps)
        
    except:
        
        print("ERROR: " + result.error)
        print('Fail')
        toggleRedLED()
        return False
    else:
        #extract relevant data
        sent_mbps = int(result.sent_Mbps)
        received_mbps = int(result.received_Mbps)

        if sent_mbps >= 850 and received_mbps >= 850:
            print('Pass!') 
            toggleGreenLED()
            return True
        elif sent_mbps < 850 or received_mbps < 850:
            print('Fail')
            print('sent_mbps: ')
            print(sent_mbps)
            print('received_mbps: ')
            print(received_mbps)
            toggleRedLED()
            return False
        else:
            print('Fail')
            toggleRedLED()
            return False

def startProgram(start_value):
    print("running main")
    if start_value == True:
        try:
            # Create and launch a thread
            from threading import Thread
            t = Thread(target = runLanTest) 
            t.start()
            t.join()
        except:
            print("error running test")

        
   
GPIO.add_event_detect(start_btn, GPIO.FALLING, callback=startProgram(True), bouncetime=50)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    startProgram(False)
```

At first I thought it was an issue with my startProgram func. So I tested it with a simple print out.

```
def eventTestPrint():
   print("running start_btn callback")

GPIO.add_event_detect(start_btn, GPIO.FALLING, callback=eventTestPrint(), bouncetime=50)
```

The results are the same though:

```
running start_btn callback

GPIO.add_event_detect(start_btn, GPIO.FALLING, callback=eventTestPrint(), bouncetime=50)
TypeError: Parameter must be callable
```

It seemed to be running just fine before I added the code for the thread, but I don't remember exactly, been working on it for a while.